# Insert New data without overwriting existing data everytime the script runs( Openpyxl: python)

Tags: python, excel, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, openpyxl

I'm having trouble with openpyxl. The issue I'm having:

I'm trying to run an hourly excel report using data I have scraped on-line via (BS4).
I have assigned the data to a list and can unpack it to print in powershell and within excel however every-time I run the script it overwrites the previous data. I would like to find out how to print the data to a new row every time the script runs.

The problem loop:

```
c = 1 
for cell_val in status:
    sheet1.cell(row=2, column=c).value = cell_val
    c += 1
    print(c)
```

Comment: Is your problem finding an empty row into which you can put new values (you're always overwriting row 2)?

Comment: Yeah, the code below solved it thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use `ws.max_row`?

```
for col_idx, cell_val in enumerate(status, 1):
    sheet1.cell(row=sheet1.max_row+1, column=col_idx, value=cell_val)
```

Or even just

`sheet1.append(status)`

Comment: Thanks for that, I could kiss you. sheet1.append(status) works a treat